mulesoft Logger(Core) - ERROR StatusConsoleListener Attempted to append to non-started appender
Hello MuleSoft Developers,
I am using Mulesoft's Logger Core component, which is working locally. However, on the server, it always shows an error related to the Logger component, as shown below, although everything is working fine. Any ideas or suggestions are more than welcome!

 ### employeeId-> "xxx" , companyCode ->"yyy" is sent successfully 
## ERROR StatusConsoleListener Attempted to append to non-started appender AnypointMonitoringFileAppender ERROR StatusConsoleListener Attempted to append to non-started appender AnypointMonitoringFileAppender


Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. See Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?. For Mule components copy the text from the XML view.

Also [edit] the question to add: where are you deploying, a standalone Mule runtime, CloudHub 1.0, CloudHub 2.0, Runtime Fabric? Which version of Mule? Are you using Anypoint Monitoring? add the log4j2.xml configuration file to the question (use [edit] and paste as text using [code block] format).

Thanks for hints. i think i found the reason problem should be log4j2.xml setting

If you find the fix, you can add the solution as answer to your question. It may help others in future
